# Why fragment shader didn't attach?

Tags: c, opengl, shader

I'm pretty new to modern OpenGL (3.0+) and right now I'm trying to create a basic white triangle on a black background. I'm on Mac OS X Mavericks 10.9.2, using GLFW 3.0.4 to create window, GLEW 1.10.0 to load extensions. You can find the [full source code here.](http://cl.ly/code/342f2Q440s3M)

My problem is, that my fragment shader doesn't want to be attached to my program. I checked both the program (`glIsProgram()`) and the shader (`glIsShader`) and they both passed. The shaders are compiling, and the program is linking..

However my code compiles, runs and doesn't throw any error, I only got a running window with a black background but without the white triangle. Here is the part, I think that is broken somehow (or at least this is where I can find the error):

```c
const char* opengl_get_error(void)
{
    switch (glGetError())
    {
        case 0x0500: return "GL_INVALID_ENUM​";
        case 0x0501: return "GL_INVALID_VALUE​";
        case 0x0502: return "GL_INVALID_OPERATION​";
        case 0x0503: return "GL_STACK_OVERFLOW​";
        case 0x0504: return "GL_STACK_UNDERFLOW​";
        case 0x0505: return "GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY​";
        case 0x0506: return "GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION​";
        case 0x8031: return "GL_TABLE_TOO_LARGE​";
            default: return "GL_NO_ERROR";
    }
}

void check_attached_shaders(GLuint program)
{
    GLsizei count = 0;
    GLuint shaders[] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
    glGetAttachedShaders(program, 4, &count, shaders);
    printf(">>> ERROR: %s\n", opengl_get_error());
    printf("\tnumber of shaders: %d\n", count);
    for (int i=0; i < 4; i++) printf("\tshader_id: %d\n", shaders[i]);
}

...

    // Get program ID
    GLuint programID = glCreateProgram();

    // Attach shaders
/* CHECKING: */ check_attached_shaders(programID);
    glAttachShader(programID, vert_shader);
/* CHECKING: */ check_attached_shaders(programID);
    glAttachShader(programID, frag_shader);
/* CHECKING: */ check_attached_shaders(programID);

    // Link shader program
    glLinkProgram(programID);

...
```

And I have this output:

```c
/*
>>> ERROR: GL_NO_ERROR
    number of shaders: 0
    shader_id: 0
    shader_id: 0
    shader_id: 0
    shader_id: 0
>>> ERROR: GL_NO_ERROR
    number of shaders: 1
    shader_id: 1
    shader_id: 0
    shader_id: 0
    shader_id: 0
>>> ERROR: GL_INVALID_OPERATION
    number of shaders: 1
    shader_id: 1
    shader_id: 0
    shader_id: 0
    shader_id: 0
*/
```

This is what my vertex shader looks like:

```c
// OpenGL Shading Language Version 1.5.0
#version 150 core

in vec2 input_position;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(input_position, 0.f, 1);
}
```

This is how my fragment shader looks like:

```c
// OpenGL Shading Language Version 1.5.0
#version 150 core

out vec4 output_fragment;

void main()
{
    output_fragment = vec4(1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f);
}
```

Any feedback is welcome,

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it because in `create_program_from_shaders` you detach the shaders from the program after you link the program?

Comment: @doron if I comment out the `glDetachShader()` lines, it still doesn't work, and I still have the `GL_INVALID_OPERATOR` error.

Comment: Your vertex shader miss at least the Projection matrix

Comment: @j-p I changed my vertex shader to this: http://cl.ly/code/311T3K0e2Q10 still doesn't work..

Comment: Why are you using "magic" hexadecimal numbers in the opengl_get_error switch statement instead of human readable tokens? Also you must call `glGetError` or in your case `opengl_get_error` in a loop until it returns GL_NO_ERROR, since in OpenGL errors can accumulate.

Comment: your `create_shader_from_file` returns 0 or 1 to indicate success or failure, but you use the result as a shaderID. Most likely you are attaching the same shader twice.

Comment: @DragosCalin THAT'S THE ONE!!!!! THANK YOU, it is finally working now! If you write it as an answer I can accept it!

Comment: @datenwolf fair enough, I will update that in my code, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in comments, the issue was in the function `GLuint create_shader_from_file(GLchar *path, GLenum shader_type)` which compiled a shader from a source file and returned 0 or 1 to indicate failure or success.

The result was then used as a shader ID.